# LibGDX Resolution too big

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I was making a game and as the screen dimensions I choosed 1280x720(hd resolution). My phone has double that resolution and when I ran it for the first time on my phone I was surprised that the resolution is still that big. How is this possible? I was expecting the sprites to get stretched to fit my phone's big resolution but it seems the graphics stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK.

1. try to use StretchViewport in viewport to supports working with a virtual screen size (assuming that you already defining your camera using virtual unit)
2. have you defined/overriden resize method like

`public void resize(int width, int height) {
      camera.viewportWidth = (your VIEWPORT_HEIGHT unit / height) * width;
      camera.update();
}`